# Cannot GET /path/to/service

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

Running kubernetes in AWS. I have couple of services running in the cluster which I want to access from my DNS name via contextual paths. 
Setup the ingress controller by following this steps: https://daemonza.github.io/2017/02/13/kubernetes-nginx-ingress-controller/

I am successfully able to get default-backend-server and /healthz api. But I am getting "Cannot GET /home" ( Which is a custom path to my service ). I am able to access that service through nodePort and within the cluster.

I have attached [hello service](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B03gYsR5w0JLM3FMM0ZPN0ZSZ3M), [nginx](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B03gYsR5w0JLb05GNUQxS244OTg) and [ingress](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B03gYsR5w0JLemxnVEtJVmxNU0E)

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: The linked documents are not publicly available. Please provide the Ingress resource manifest as well.

Comment: I updated the ingress controller image and its now working. https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/issues/349